# Table with expandable columns

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a table in react Js. The table would have two rows expandable rows say A and B. When clicking on row A, json result from a rest service will be shown in form of table. and clicking on row B , will show json from another rest service. basically it would a table with two  expandable columns and clicking on each of them would show different Jsons. I am currently using ReactTable library for creating table. Though table is created but unable to make rows expandable in that.Please help in that.

Representation of requirement is below:

Below is the state when row A and row B will be expanded;

Row A

field1       field2        field3         field4      field5

field1       field2        field3         field4      field5

Row B

field1       field2        field3         field4      field5

field1       field2        field3         field4      field5

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to do is keep two buttons, button A and B. And below each button will be a table with the columns preset as the fields that will be returned in JSON. When you press button A, it will fetch the data. If number of data is > 0, The button displays the table, where you run a `.map()` on the results and render each row with the data. A sample of how to render row data:

```
// In your render method: 
  let id = 0;
  const ItemsList = results.map((item) => {
      ++id; 
      return (
          <tr key={{id}}>
              <td>item.id</td>
              <td>item.name</td>
          </tr>
      );
   });

   return (results.length > 0) : (
    <table>
       <thead> 
           <tr><th>ID</th><th>NAME</th></tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <ItemsList />
        </tbody>
    </table>
   ) : null;
 });
); `
```